# My form doesn't save the value that it gets from the template, django

Tags: django

I want to add a car information from the form but  it sees the form as invalid. It doesn't add the car into my car inventory. Where do I make the mistake?

Here is my views.py

```
def add_car_step_1(request):
    form = AddCarForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddCarForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            brand = form.cleaned_data['brand']
            status_of_car = form.cleaned_data['status_of_car']
            (...)
            fuel_type = form.cleaned_data['fuel_type']
            no_of_owners = form.cleaned_data['no_of_owners']

            

            data = {
                'brand': brand,
                'status_of_car': status_of_car,
                (...)
                'fuel_type': fuel_type,
                'no_of_owners': no_of_owners,

            }

            form.save()

            return render(request, 'cars/cars.html', data)
    return render(request, 'cars/add_car_step_1.html', context={'form': form})
```

Here is my forms.py

```
class AddCarForm(forms.ModelForm):

    description = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = [
            'car_title',
            'city',
           (...)
            'fuel_type',
            'no_of_owners',
            
        ]
```

Sorry  that the details are a bit much.

Comment: Please also include your template where you render your form. Are all the fields listed in Meta which is required in your model?

Comment: there's a lot of issues here, by my reading of it: 1. you're using ModelForm but then treating it like a normal Form, e.g. grabbing data from form.cleaned_data -- this is only necessary with the basic Form class; ModelForm takes care of all that behavior for you when you save it; 2. the POST branch of your view function is building and returning a data dict, and I have no idea why; and finally the POST branch is returning a render function, when all it should be doing is returning an HttpResponseRedirect after the form's connected model has been saved.